# Need to remove plus (+) sign from barcode after scanning in Excel?

Tags: excel

My data:

[image: Data]

Function Used

[image: Function Used]

I have this data in Excel. When i scan this Barcode using scanner, its scanning the name ( Dawood khan) like this (D+A+W+O+O+D +K+H+A+N)

I don't want that plus (+) sign when I scan it.

I am using 3 of 9 code (FONT).

I tried using just using this function (*Dawood khan*) still its giving me same output.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use substitute...

```
=Substitute (a1,"+","")
```

Replacing a1 with the correct cell ref. Else a find/replace to replace '+' with nothing would achieve the same result.

Comment: Actually i want to add some function in the barcode so when i scan it, it gives me my name without plus sign. I can remove plus sign after data is added that is easy.

Comment: You could use a macro to change it immediately after scanning. If you consider a macro to be an acceptable solution that is

Answer (score 0):

Try making it all-caps. Lower-cased characters are encoded with a "+".

`=CONCATENATE("*",UPPER(D4),"*")`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Full_ASCII_Code_39